# Word Cloud showing several ' amongst words and not sure why

Tags: python, word-cloud, stop-words

I tried to exclude them with a " ' " but that failed.  Not sure where they are pulling from as they are not in the document. Thanks for any help

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Imme21/WordCloud/main/StockData3.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)
df.dropna(inplace = True)
text = df['Stock'].values

wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color = 'white',
            stopwords = ['Date','Stock', 'Tickers', 
                         'Open','Close', 'High', 
                         'Low', 'IV', 'under',
                         'over', 'price', 'change', 
                         '%', 'null']).generate(str(text))


plt.imshow(wordcloud) 
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to how you obtain the string from the values in the dataframe column. Specifically, `text = df['Stock'].values` and `.generate(str(text)`.

Using [`pandas.Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) will produce the "correct" string and will give you the desired outcome:

```py
...
>>> text = df['Stock'].str.cat(sep=' ')
...
>>> wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color = 'white',
            stopwords = ['Date','Stock', 'Tickers', 
                         'Open','Close', 'High', 
                         'Low', 'IV', 'under',
                         'over', 'price', 'change', 
                         '%', 'null']).generate(text)
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you have an array of strings, where each string is contained with a quotes. Wordcloud assumes that the trailing apostrophe can be a part of word (so it can process words like can't aren't). See [this post](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/505) for more information.

You can resolve this issue by having a string of space separated words and not a list. ' '.join(text) should solve your problem

```
# You read a sring from file and converted it to array
text = df['Stock'].values
>>> text
array(['GME', 'SPY', 'TSLA', 'PLTR', 'AAPL', 'AMC', 'RKT', 'NIO', 'DIS',
.....

text = ' '.join(text)
>>> text
'GME SPY TSLA PLTR AAPL AMC RKT NIO.....
```

That should take care of the right trailing quotes or apostrophes in your word cloud.

Comment: I see my issue and I think your solution would work if the data wasn't ever growing.  Its based of top 10 stocks per day and I would have to constantly update the array doing it this way. Nikolaos had a solution that worked better for my needs. Thank you though.